Parse XML using pl sql

583761826510
9132550000
null
<meterBadgeNo>2113237835116</meterBadgeNo>

<previousMtrReads/>

<currentMtrReads>

  <meterReadSource>MOBILEAPP</meterReadSource>

  <readerRemark>MC</readerRemark>

  <registers>

    <readSequence>1</readSequence>

    <readType>50</readType>

    <reading>30</reading>

    <uomCode>KWH</uomCode>

  </registers>

  <registers>

    <readSequence>2</readSequence>

    <readType>50</readType>

    <reading>1</reading>

    <uomCode>KW</uomCode>

  </registers>

</currentMtrReads>

<meterSerialNo>37835116</meterSerialNo>

<meterStatus>A</meterStatus>

<billedUnits>

  <billed>

    <billedUom>KW</billedUom>

    <startReading>0.000000</startReading>

    <endReading>0.000000</endReading>

    <startDttm>2020-07-11-11.49.00</startDttm>

    <endDttm>2020-09-22-23.59.59</endDttm>

    <billedUnits>0.000000</billedUnits>

  </billed>

  <billed>

    <billedUom>KWH</billedUom>

    <startReading>7410.000000</startReading>

    <endReading>7812.640000</endReading>

    <startDttm>2020-07-11-11.49.00</startDttm>

    <endDttm>2020-09-22-23.59.59</endDttm>

    <billedUnits>402.640000</billedUnits>

  </billed>

</billedUnits>

<billingHeads/>

<billId>913255668208</billId>

<highLow>N</highLow>

<billCycleCode>AAON</billCycleCode>

<billedUnit>402.640000</billedUnit>

<billedDays>73.000000</billedDays>

<tariffCategory>DS</tariffCategory>

<locationType>URBAN</locationType>

<supplyVoltage>0.23</supplyVoltage>

<sanctionLoad>2.3000000</sanctionLoad>

<billType>PR</billType>

<arrears>0.46</arrears>

<billDueDt>2020-10-05</billDueDt>

<address>J 103 RAIL VIHAR</address>

<personName>SANJEEV KUMAR</personName>

<phone>9569756585</phone>

<manufacture>HSPL</manufacture>

<fixedCharge>0</fixedCharge>

<energyCharge>1840.11</energyCharge>

<amtToCoverMmc>0</amtToCoverMmc>

<fuelSurchargAdj>148.97</fuelSurchargAdj>

<excessLoadSurcharge>0</excessLoadSurcharge>

<mtrServiceCharge>48.67</mtrServiceCharge>

<lineServiceCharge>0</lineServiceCharge>

<solarRebate>0</solarRebate>

<capacitorSurcharge>0</capacitorSurcharge>

<womenRebate>0</womenRebate>

<electrictyDuty>40.26</electrictyDuty>

<muncipalTax>39.78</muncipalTax>

<govtSubsidy>-833.51</govtSubsidy>

<totalCurrCharges>1284.28</totalCurrCharges>

<netPayAmtBeforeDue>1260</netPayAmtBeforeDue>

<payAfterDue>1295</payAfterDue>

<surcharge>35</surcharge>

<netSundry>-24.96</netSundry>

<billMYear>SEP20</billMYear>

<billDate>2020-09-22-15.05.42</billDate>

<lastPayment>1248.00</lastPayment>

<lastPayDate>2020-07-14</lastPayDate>

<meterSecurity>0.00</meterSecurity>

<acd>139.00</acd>

<mf>1.00000</mf>

<nonEnergyCharg>0</nonEnergyCharg>

<provAdj>0.00</provAdj>

<sdo>SDO21132</sdo>

This data is stored in a column of my table the table contains multiple XML as an individual record I want to parse it in such if any non observed node comes the query automatically selects it as a column is it possible in pl sql and also I want to create a table of these selected columns using the XML table I can manually select each node but when you are dealing with 500000 records it not possible to go through each record .
SO FOR CLARIFICATION
<CONSUMERDETAILS/>
<PERID><10000/>
<DOC><01/10/24/>
<MTR_DETAILS/>
<MTR_ID><1900011/>
<MTR_NO><2009876/>
<MTR_READ_DETAILS/>
<UOM_CD><KWH/>
<UNITS><220/>

SIMILARLY MULTIPLE NODES ARE THERE
I WANT THE PROCEDURE WHICH SELECT THE NODE AS LIKE PER_ID,DOC,UOM_CD AS A COLUMN OF SQL TABLE AND VALUES AS ROWS OF THAT TABLE

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS and its version.

Please edit your original question and provide a minimal reproducible example: ##1-4 in its entirety.
